# btrfs balance "No space left on device" with no success on any -dusage and -musage values

Tags: disk-usage, lvm, btrfs, df

I have the following issue with `btrfs balance start /` on a `btrfs` on an 140 GB LVM with 4 physical device (in case that matters):

- `sudo btrfs balance start /` fails with `ERROR: error during balancing '/': No space left on device`
- `sudo btrfs balance start / -dusage=83` causes `Done, had to relocate 0 out of 145 chunks` (multiple values < 83 (0, 20, 60, 80) cause the same result)
- `sudo btrfs balance start / -dusage=84` causes `ERROR: error during balancing '/': No space left on device` (multiple values > 84 (90, 95) cause the same result)
- `sudo btrfs balance start / -musage=1` causes `ERROR: error during balancing '/': No space left on device`
- `sudo btrfs balance start / -musage=0` results in `Done, had to relocate 1 out of 144 chunks` or `Done, had to relocate 2 out of 145 chunks` during multiple invokations without any pattern I recognize

`du -x -h /` reports 41 GB of file size which makes me believe that btrfs could provide more free space than it does.

`dmesg` contains multiple

```
[1579308.336992] BTRFS info (device dm-0): 1 enospc errors during balance
```

After adding the mount option `enospc_debug` I see a lot of

```
[1584022.768838] BTRFS: block group 2562951479296 has 1073741824 bytes, 1040130048 used 0 pinned 0 reserved 
[1584022.768840] BTRFS critical (device dm-0): entry offset 2562951479296, bytes 561152, bitmap yes
[1584022.768847] BTRFS critical (device dm-0): entry offset 2563085697024, bytes 425984, bitmap yes
[1584022.768854] BTRFS critical (device dm-0): entry offset 2563219914752, bytes 1355776, bitmap yes
[1584022.768861] BTRFS critical (device dm-0): entry offset 2563354132480, bytes 606208, bitmap yes
[1584022.768867] BTRFS critical (device dm-0): entry offset 2563488350208, bytes 11956224, bitmap yes
[1584022.768874] BTRFS critical (device dm-0): entry offset 2563614498816, bytes 495616, bitmap no
[1584022.768881] BTRFS critical (device dm-0): entry offset 2563616403456, bytes 28672, bitmap no
[1584022.768888] BTRFS critical (device dm-0): entry offset 2563616440320, bytes 40960, bitmap no
[1584022.768895] BTRFS critical (device dm-0): entry offset 2563622567936, bytes 16375808, bitmap yes
[1584022.768902] BTRFS critical (device dm-0): entry offset 2563756785664, bytes 1331200, bitmap yes
[1584022.768909] BTRFS critical (device dm-0): entry offset 2563891003392, bytes 434176, bitmap yes
[1584022.768915] BTRFS info (device dm-0): block group has cluster?: no
[1584022.768917] BTRFS info (device dm-0): 0 blocks of free space at or bigger than bytes is
```

in `dmesg`.

[A thread on the Linux mailing list](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-btrfs/msg46009.html) recommends to use a newer kernel.

I'm experiencing this issue since Ubuntu 15.10 and now 16.04 with Linux 4.4.0-34-generic and 4.4.6 with `btrfs-progs` v4.7.3.

Comment: Using LVM with btrfs is not a good idea. Btrfs has its own feature to be located on many physical devices.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, try deleting space or putting it onto a drive. If you plug in a removable media such as a USB usually it can act as extra space and prevent errors.

Comment: Seems like a good idea. Please add the commands.

Comment: You cannot mount devices when you have no space on your root partition.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Try this command:

```
sudo btrfs subvolume list /
```

If you see there something like

```
@apt-snapshot-release-upgrade-zesty-2017-07-27_23:31:45
```

then you may get quite a lot of free space by removing all apt-release snapshots older than 1 day:

```
sudo apt install apt-btrfs-snapshot
sudo apt-btrfs-snapshot delete-older-than 1d
```

*Note: My linux drive is only 25GB large. Before upgrading to Ubuntu 17.04, I had about 10GB of free space, but after the upgrade there was only 1GB left and I wasn't even able to write 10MB file to the disk. After removing the apt-snapshot, I gained another 8GB of free space.*